# RDS Aurora Mysql and ECS connection timeouts (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, pymysql

I have an ECS cluster with two Tasks running the same container/image. I terraform the cluster and the task-def to start my service. Recently the first task starts fine, but the second gets 'stuck'. The logs indicate a connection timeout as the connection pool is being called for. Eventually the second task/container will stop, drain and new one starts. This cycle repeats until the second instance connects and all is well. Everything seems to be functioning and the first container holds the connection and I don't see further timeouts once the second container gets going. What's going on?

Python is real simple (based on the Mega Tutorial by Grinberg):

- Flask
- Flask-Sqlalchemy
- pymysql

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# This import will give me the missing MySQLdb python object
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

# Create the DB engine object
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    db.init_app(discipline)
    migrate.init_app(discipline, db)
```

I tried this for a bit, but didn't help:

```
    SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        'connect_args': {
            'connect_timeout': 30
        }
    }
```

Log files:

```
  File "/home/-/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/-/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my.cluster-on.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/-/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 613, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Sort of a vague question, I know. But is there anything obvious I'm overlooking in terms of settings that would help, or specifically for ECS/RDS?

One other thing to add - running with gunicorn - 3 workers:

```
exec gunicorn -b :5000 -w 3 --log-level=warning --access-logfile - --error-logfile - my_app:"create_app()"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did finally figure this out. Essentially it was NACLs and Security Groups. Each ECS task launches in a specific subnet, but the RDS instance was unreachable. The health check kills the task and launches another, randomly assigning a new subnet, one that may or may not have a path to RDS, until eventually a connection can be made and the task stays running. Being paranoid about internet access to resources, over time my subnet usage, ENIs and SGs got a bit wonky. After tidying my subnet/NACL/SG configuration everything worked fine. Hope this helps others.

Comment: what do you mean by "tidying up"? A little more detail might help others...